# How can I detect the presence of Intel Quick Sync from c++ code?

Tags: c++, video

I want to detect whether Intel Quick Sync is present and enabled on the processor.  FYI, it may be disabled (powered down) if you have no video cable plugged into the motherboard, or can be disabled in the BIOS.
Thanks
Ron

Answer (score 0):

There is no general solution for something like this, the code would have to be specific to the OS you are running.  It would likely boil down to a system call to determine the feature set of the processor you are running i.e. maybe something like `cat /proc/cpuinfo` if you were running Linux for example.

There are multiple ways to execute a system call in C++. Take a look at some of the previous answers here [How to execute a command and get output of command within C++ using POSIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c-using-posix)

Answer (score 0):

You can port the [Intel System Analyzer Utility for Linux](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/mss-sys-analyzer-linux.html) to C++ from Python. That's what I ended up doing.

That tool uses the output of `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and `lspci` to collect some info about the CPU, GPU, and software installation.